# Python: creating a 2d list through multiplying list by number buggy?

Tags: python, arrays

We know that in python you can multiply a list by a number:

```
[2]*3=[2,2,2]
```

I used this idea to create a 2d array:

```
exploded=[["O"]*7]*6
```

resulting in

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

However, when I try to change an element of this 2d array:

```
exploded[0][0]=9
```

instead of only that one element at position (0,0) changes, all elements at position (x,0) changes where x is 0 to len(exploded)-1.

```
[[9, 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], [9, 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], [9, 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], [9, 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], [9, 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], [9, 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

If I assign the 2d array to exploded directly, then this issue doesn't occur, so I think it has to be something about multiplying lists by a number. Can someone explain what the error/bug here is and how [2]*3 actually works?

Comment: You have multiple pointers to the same list, not different lists

Comment: It's not "multiplication" as in maths. The asterisk operator in this case is used to duplicate the same object (same memory location).